# Matlab Rounding Computation Error

Tags: matlab, rounding

Under Matlab 2014b, when making:

```
round((0.1:0.2:1)/0.2)
```

I obtain:

```
1 2 3 3 5
```

Instead of

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Is there a way to fix such weird computation? Why this happens? Why so weird? This repeats for other values, not only `n=0.2`.

EDIT: I checked the duplicate but, do the scenario changes when using `ceil` so the floating point threshold is not in the half integer (0.5, 1.5, 2.5) but in the integer (1.0, 2.0, 3.0)? What if i use some other representation, like `single`? Or any other more predictable?

Comment: `round((0.1:0.2+eps:1)./0.2)`

Comment: get use to floating point accuracy...

Comment: You can just use [`ceil`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ceil.html) instead of `round`.

Comment: I suppose... `ceil` is equally prone to fail that `round` under the same scenario?

Comment: Any operation where you are converting from floating point to integer values will potentially suffer this kind of error. This is because they are threshold based. `round` has a threshold at 0.5, so if your floating-point numbers all hover around that value, with slight errors above and below, you're going to see problems like what you have in your question. Likewise, `ceil` or `floor` will show the same problems if your floating-point numbers are close to integer values. The key is to pick thresholds that are farthest from your areas of numeric uncertainty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the question got reopened, I'll briefly mention that adding 1.3+0.2 with floats can result in 2.49999999999 or in 2.5000000001 etc. the `round` will act according to the floating point error.

Comment: `ceil` fixed the error, but is this apparent? I cannot find a case when `ceil` fails...